# MySql query where any date between two dates is between two dates

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I have a MySQL Datatable with an ID, two datetime and a boolean column.

Looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Example` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Date1` date NOT NULL,
 `Date2` date NOT NULL,
 `Answered` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I have a startdate and an enddate, and I need a sql query which gives me that rows, where **any** **day** **between** the **startdate** and the **enddate** is **between** **Date1** and **Date2**!

What works is that query, wich gives me those rows, where the **Date1** is **between** the **startdate** and the **enddate** and **Aswered** **= 1**:

```
    $proof = "select * from Example where Date1 
    between '$startdate' and '$enddate' and Answered = 1";
```

But I dont know how to do that with all dates between two dates

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: You should include sample data and desire output.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: no thats not that what I am seaching for

Comment: Show some sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: I have no sample data and the expected result should be an array of datatablerows where any day between a startdate and an enddate is between Date1 and Date2

Comment: If you dont have sample data how will you test your query? Dont be lazy and prepare a proper question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok based on the 2 answers above I solved my problem,
this is the query I need:

```
SELECT * FROM `Example`
WHERE ('$startdate' BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2) 
    OR ('$enddate' BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2)
    OR (Date1 BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') 
    OR (Date2 BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') 
    AND Answered = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you'd want:

```
SELECT * FROM Example 
WHERE (Date1 BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') 
    AND (Date2 BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') 
    AND Answered = 1
```

Comment: I want to know if any Day from the timespan between the startdate and the enddate is inside the timespan between Date1 and Date2

Comment: that SQL statement should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the start and end points, what about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Example` 
WHERE `Answered` = 1
AND `Date1` >= '$startdate'
AND `Date2` <= '$enddate'
```

If you do not want to include them in the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Example` 
WHERE `Answered` = 1
AND `Date1` > '$startdate'
AND `Date2` < '$enddate'
```

You should probably read here too: [PHP: Prepared Statements - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thats not that what I am searching for, I want to know if any Day from the timespan between the startdate and the enddate is inside the timespan between Date1 and Date2

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you exact data between two dates with answered 1

```
SELECT * FROM `Example`
WHERE ( `Date1` <= '$startdate' and `Date2` >= '$startdate' )
OR ( '$startdate' <= `Date1`  and '$enddate' >= `Date1` )
OR ( `Date1` < '$enddate' and `Date2` >= '$enddate' )
AND `Aswered` = 1
```